# Allow Users to change a list of specific Ranges in a workbook across multiple Worksheets and lock others

Tags: excel, vba, security

I am researching a request to lockdown a workbook that has a about a dozen or so
worksheets to produce quotes that allows for user input in various cells and ranges
across 3 or 4 worksheets.  The workbook uses vba code and formulas to calculate
different quotes and output information.  I was wondering how do I allow this information to change
and remain locked from editing after the calculation is run but allow the user to the ability to change a set list of ranges.

I have seen the following:

```
myWorksheet.Protect contents:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True
```

as a suggestion but that applies to the worksheet itself and was wondering if there was a method to use this per range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this:
Unlocking the cells which you want to edit when the sheet is protected.
It is done in the Format Cells menu.

**Formulas always update** even if all cells are protected.

If you want a macro to do changes to locked cells on a protected sheet, you have to unprotect the sheet before it does the changes to the cells, and after that you need to protect it again.

```
Sub ProtectionTest()
    
    'some lines of code
    
    Worksheets("sheet1").Unprotect
    
    'some changes to the (locked) cells
    
    Worksheets("sheet1").Protect
    
End Sub
```

[image]

This code:

```
myWorksheet.Protect contents:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True
```

You need to run every time when you open the workbook. Because the userinterfaceonly will not get saved, the workbook will "forget" it after closing. So you could write an event on Workbook open that will save your sheets with userinterfaceonly = true

These are the only options. I hope I understood you right.

Comment: This unfortunately does the opposite of what I am looking for. I am looking to protect the whole sheet (Multiple sheets) and only allow entry in certain ranges on each sheet. But also still allow changes to the protected sheet by VBA and formulas.  This method will lock the entire sheet and protect and unprotect only certain ranges by password

Comment: @Eagle1 Please see my new answer above.